# Scala - Types and Instantiation

Tags: scala

```
scala> val a1 = scala.concurrent.Promise[Int]
a1: scala.concurrent.Promise[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@10d59286
```

I'm not able to understand how an instance of DefaultPromise is created above. It is understandable that in the below example, `()` makes a call to `apply()` and DefaultPromise is created

```
scala> val a2 = scala.concurrent.Promise[Int]()
a2: scala.concurrent.Promise[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@140e5a13
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not able to understand how an instance of DefaultPromise is created above

Since you explicitly pass a type parameter (`[Int]`) to the invocation (thanks @Jasper for the clarification), the compiler treats the call as if you'd called `Promise.apply[Int]()`, since an object cannot have a type parameter.

We can see this exploring the code. If we call `Promise[Int]`, the compiler interpets:

```
private[this] val res2: scala.concurrent.Promise[Int] = scala.concurrent.Promise.apply[Int]();
```

On the contrary, if we don't supply a type parameter, we get `Promise.type`:

```
private[this] val res3: concurrent.Promise.type = scala.concurrent.Promise;
```

Comment: If we omit the parenthesis, the companion object (if one exists) will be assigned to the variable. If no companion object exists, a compilation error will occur. It does not create an instance if we omit the parenthesis. For example, if a `Person` class and a `Person` companion object exist, `val a = Person` will result in `a: Person.type = Person$@51c693d`. This is different from `val b = new Person` which will result in `b : Person = Person@1efe439d`

Comment: You pass a type parameter (`Int`) to the `apply` method. That's how the compiler knows you are calling `apply`; an object has no type parameters.

Comment: @Jasper-M Thanks. Could you explain in a bit more detail - may be with an example or a link to it?

Comment: @saravana_pc I expanded and corrected my answer a bit. See if that answers what you're looking for.

Comment: I would expand `Promise.type` part a bit, what we have there is another reference to the object `scala.concurrent.Promise`, which has type `Promise.type`.

Comment: @saravana_pc You can only assign to a variable something that has a value. Class `Person` does not have a value, nor does any other type. So in `val p = Person` `p` can only be an object `Person` (companion or not), or `Person#apply` call.